# How to use rest api in kivy to upload a file to a django website

Tags: python, django, kivy

I am currently working on a system that involves building a website an a mobile application. I am using kivy to build my application however am facing an issue with using the django rest api to upload files to the site through kivy. How can I go about it.

This is my function in main.py for uploading the file

```py
def upload(self, filepass, filename):
    print(str(filename))
    try:
        requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/', filepass)
    except:
        toast('Could not upload file')
```

This is my api view in my views.py

```py
class FileUploadView(APIView):
    parser_class = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data['files'])

      if file_serializer.is_valid():
          file_serializer.save()
          return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
          return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my models.py for the database of the uploaded file

```py
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='landbroker/', default='default.png')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name
```

This is my serializers.py for the file upload

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import File

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = "__all__"
```

And finally my urls.py

```py
path('upload/', views.FileUploadView.as_view())
```

With all that, whenever I try to submit the image django outputs unsupported file format. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a full year with no answer. But I now think that if someone just uses get in the django site without verifying the form of the sent media it would actually work.